# Youtube Javascript API pause and Play Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I've been struggling with this for some days now. I use the function below to control a youtube video embedded with an iframe. The initialize function works properly. The problem is the onPlayerStateChange function. I'm trying to control the pause and play using the same button but it doesn't seem to run properly. It doesn't pause the video and the video itself cracks(plays at a very slow rate).

```
var player, time_update_interval = 0;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('videod', {
        playerVars: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        events: {
            'onReady': doThisFirst,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}
function doThisFirst(){
    updateTimerDisplay();
    clearInterval(time_update_interval);
    time_update_interval = setInterval(function () {
        updateTimerDisplay();
    }, 1000);
    $('#volume-input').val(Math.round(player.getVolume()));
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {  // If video is playing…
              var stop = document.getElementsByClassName('playButton');
              stop[0].click(player.pauseVideo());
        }
        else{    // If video – pause
            var start = document.getElementsByClassName('playButton');
            start[0].click(player.playVideo());
        }
      }
```

Comment: Did you check how often `onPlayerStateChange` is called? Possible you got looped changing of video state  from playing to pause and back?

Comment: I did. but I still couldn't correct it to make the button work.